# Create a button that changes between red and green

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, colors

I want to create a simple button that changes between the colors red and green as I click them to indicate that something has been completed. Does anyone know of a simple way to get a button to change back and forth between colors? The setup of the page isn't how I want it yet but the button needs to be configured before I can format the rest of the page how I would like. I left out the CSS that deals with the body and other things like the headings.
Here is what I have so far after looking online for a while:

```js
function colorChange(id) {
  var e1 = document.getElementById(id);
  var currentClass = el.getAttribute("class");
  if(currentClass == 'classA') {
    el.setAttribute("class", "classB");
  }
  else {
    el.setAttribute("class", "classA");
  }
}
```

```css
#select {
    width: 10em;
    height: 1.5em;
}

.classA {
    background: red;
}

.classB {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="select" onclick="colorchange('select')" class="classA" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the native JavaScript version. You first query the button directly with the `getElementById` selector. You then add an event listener, waiting for the click event.

The `classList`, although it returns an array, you can't use `indexOf` on it. However, you can use `contains` with it. It's also important to note that classList is not available in Internet Explorer 9 or earlier versions

```js
var button = document.getElementById('my-button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (button.classList.contains('red')) {   
      button.classList.remove('red');
      button.classList.add('green');
      button.innerHTML = 'Done';
    }
    else {
      button.classList.remove('green');
      button.classList.add('red');
      button.innerHTML = 'Not Done';
    }
});
```

```css
.green { background: green; }
.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<button id='my-button' class='green'>Change Color</button>
```

This is best accomplished through jQuery and it's `toggleClass` function.

```js
$('#my-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).text($(this).hasClass('red') ? 'Done': 'Not Done');
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
});
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='my-button' class='red'>Change Color</button>
```

As you can see above, it's much easier in jQuery.

Comment: Where do I put the jQuery at? And if you are going to make a javascript version then I can just wait for that.

Comment: This is the solution. The JavaScript version works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Would I also be able to make the text change between things like "Done" and "Not Done"? I would want them to go with Green and Red respectively.

Comment: This no longer works if I try to use two buttons. Why is that? The first one I put in works but now the second on doesn't. Would it be because of the unsorted list and list items that I have?

Comment: Now it only works in one instance of the button no matter where I put it. Any suggestions?

Comment: That can be fixed by adding an id for the button. I also fixed the text toggling

Answer (score 2):

You only need to be more careful with your syntax. `colorchange` on your input vs `colorChange` in your JS (capital 'C') and and `e1` is different to `el` (1 vs L).

```js
function colorChange(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var currentClass = el.getAttribute("class");
  if(currentClass == 'classA') {
    el.setAttribute("class", "classB");
  }
  else {
    el.setAttribute("class", "classA");
  }
}
```

```css
#select {
  width: 10em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.classA {
  background: red;
}

.classB {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="select" onclick="colorChange('select')" class="classA" />
```

Comment: This is the answer. There are just a couple of typos.

Comment: This hasn't changed my result either.

Comment: @Tylersong55 try the working code snippet in the answer? It works for me in Chrome

Comment: This can be improved with ternary

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is ok. Just you have to correct these typos:

1. Change `e1` to `el` ( L instead of 1 )
2. Change `onclick="colorchange('select')"` to `onclick="colorChange('select')"`

Keep mind that you need to be more carefull, as the JavaScript is **Case sensitive**.

Have fun!

Comment: This didn't change anything in the result.

Comment: Yes, this does work, but it is a duplicate answer of the one below.

Comment: @Tylersong55 Yes it does. You just need to correct your typoes. your code works fine.

Comment: Yes, this was posted 28 mins ago, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35165948/1879895) was posted 32 mins ago.